# Adding images to slideshow using php in html

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to adjust a program for a TV screen at my local football club. I already made the site work, but now I want to make it more user friendly.

Specifically, I want to make the site work so someone can just add the images to a certain folder, and the slideshow will use all images in the folder.

The relevant part of the code is below; notice that the images are hard-coded:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/tabs.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/slider.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="corner_1">
            <?php include("inc/script.php"); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="slider" id="slider">
            <ul>
                <li style="background-image:     url('http://homedir.com/images/IMG_4947.JPG'); no-repeat center center fixed; 
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-position: center top;
    background-attachment: fixed;">
                </li>
                <li style="background-image:     url('http://homedir.com/images/IMG_4939.JPG'); no-repeat center center fixed; 
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-position: center top;
    background-attachment: fixed;">
                </li>
                <li style="background-image:     url('http://homedir.com/images/IMG_4922.JPG'); no-repeat center center fixed; 
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-position: center top;
    background-attachment: fixed;">
                </li>
            </ul> 
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I tried to make something with the glob() and echo functions in PHP, but couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a `scandir()` easily enough:

```
# I am just going to use this to clean up the html, you don't have to do this...
$style = array(
    'background: no-repeat center center fixed',
    'background-repeat: no-repeat',
    'background-size: 100% 100%',
    'background-position: center top',
    'background-attachment: fixed'
);
$style = implode('; ',$style);
# I use a define('ROOT_DIR',__DIR__) in a root-based config file to get the full path
$path = '/var/www/vhosts/domain/images';
# Scan the directory
$dir  = scandir($path);
# Loop through files in directory
foreach($dir as $file) {
    # Use our root path to make sure file exists
    # (there are . and .. that will be in the array
    if(!is_file($path.'/'.$file))
        continue;
?>
        <li style="background-image: url('http://homedir.com/images/<?php echo $file ?>'); <?php echo $style ?>">
        </li>
<?php
}
```

Comment: are you sure this is right? I get a unexpected EOF error.

Comment: Right how? Syntax wise?

Comment: Syntax it's correct. You should get an array with this line: `$dir  = scandir($path);`. You have to make sure the `$path` is valid. You can use `echo (is_dir($path))? 'valid' : 'not valid'; exit;` to check that the directory exists.